# Android Dev: PNG Problems?

Tags: android, image, png

I've tried both using XML and JAVA to create an ImageView in my Android Activity. 
Both times, I am able to get all of my other PNG resources I created a day ago to display in the ImageView. The problem is, today I created a new PNG, a crop of one of the working ones, and it will not display through either method.

Is there some guide or reference that I can use to find out why my PNG will not display?

None of the images I create today are working.

XML:

```
<ImageView
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/speak"/>
```

Java:

```
ImageView speak = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.speak);
speak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logoalt);
```

I've tried using:

```
android:src="@drawable/logoalt"
```

to no avail as well.

Comment: Is there anything interesting going on in the logcat?

Comment: I think it should be `speak.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoalt);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified that you can swap out for the images created yesterday and it works, then the problem is indeed the image.  If the old ones don't work, then you changed something in your code or layouts.

Did you create them with a different program or different options?

You could try re-saving the image from a different program, or even the Yahoo smushit service.  I would expect output from that service to be valid.  http://www.smushit.com

Answer (score 0):

How did you create your crop? Are you sure it's actually a PNG? It could be a JPEG format or anything else, saved with the extension PNG. That wouldn't work. Try to do it again, and make sure you actually save it as a PNG.